# Concern About Developing Entity Relationship Diagrams using Matrix Diagrams

Tags: sql, matrix, oracle12c, entity-relationship

I am currently enrolled in the Online Oracle Academy Database Design course, which briefly delves into the use of Matrix Diagrams to make sure all possible relationships are covered in an Entity Relationship Diagram.

The following practice problem was supplied by the course, instructing us to complete a matrix diagram for four entities: RUNNER, CITY FOR RACE, RACE TYPE, and RUNNING EVENT

[image: Problem]

The following is the supplied solution from the course:

[image: Solution]

I was able to find the following alternative solution for the same problem:
[image: Solution2]
[image: Solution3]
My concern stems from just how radically different these two ERDs are from each other. Is it better practice to come up with as many relationships as possible, even going so far as to fill out all boxes in the Matrix Diagram, or do something more akin to the first solution. Or is this simply an issue which should be handled based off of the current situation and the needs of the business that we are creating the ERD for?

Comment: Looks very much like my sophomore efforts. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. Don't add more complications unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not radically different. The second ERD has all the relationships of the first, it just expands due to the presumption that the knowledge that:

- a runner has visited a city (if for instance you want to know if runners actually made it to a race after having registered for it)
- an event may consist of multiple race types, implying a different model for what an event actually is
- or that a runner has chosen a race type (I'm having a more difficult time thinking of a sensible reason here, but there are possibilities)

is important to whatever it is this database is supporting.

If you do *not* have such a reason to track a relationship, it's wasted effort to do so. It's good to keep future possibilities in mind when considering whether you have a reason, but Ockham's Razor is very much a guiding principle in schema design.